# class constructors must be invoked with 'new' error in React-native

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

So I'm trying to use react native and aws-amplify to build a web and mobile app with one code base. Now I just added the `withAuthenticator` component to my app which works fine on the mobile part but when i run the web app in the browser I'm unable to type into the authentication field that is if I click on it the cursor appears and emmediately dissapears suprisingly though if i click and hold I'm suddenly able to type aslong as I'm holding the mouse button. So after that I tried to instead create my custom authenticator which worked fine for mobile but on the web it returned the error `class constructors must be invoked with 'new'`. My code is below hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

```
  class MySignIn extends SignIn {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);   
      this.state = {
          username: null,
          password: null,
          error: null
      }
      this.checkContact = this.checkContact.bind(this);
      this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
  }


    render() {
      if (this.props.authState !== 'signIn') {
        return null;
      }
      return(
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} behavior="padding">
        <Text>Stuff and Stuff</Text>
    </View>
      );
    }
  }

  export default withAuthenticator(Signout, false, [
    <MySignIn/>,
    <ConfirmSignIn/>,
    <VerifyContact/>,
    <SignUp/>,
    <ConfirmSignUp/>,
    <ForgotPassword/>,
    <RequireNewPassword />
  ]);
```

Comment: ```class MySignIn extends SignIn``` is this correct? ive usually imported class of ```class MySignIn extends React.Component```

Comment: that solved it thanks so much

Comment: could you tell me why this works cuz according to the docs one should use what i used. Thanks

Comment: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#customize-withauthenticator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class MySignIn extends SignIn` is this correct? ive usually imported class of `class MySignIn extends React.Component`

and that works because they have imported signIn from

```
import { ConfirmSignIn, ConfirmSignUp, ForgotPassword, RequireNewPassword, SignIn, SignUp, VerifyContact, withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
```

and hence this is a custom class component , hence it works

```
// This is my custom Sign in component
class MySignIn extends SignIn {
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

this works. Hope it helps